# highpoint rr62x RAID 5 status disable, recover saying parameter error

Tags: raid, hard-drive, raid5, data-recovery

I have been using a

```
Highpoint rr62x controller(BIOS version 1.3)
```

for about a decade now. The RAID-5 volume is containing 4 disks-each 3TB.
For the last five years my RAID has been disabled. I have three 3TB  spares to rebuild it but there is no option for a rebuild.
Every time I go into the BIOS, it shows me that there is one disk or no RAID.
But if I go into the Web GUI, it shows me three out of four disks are functioning.

There are three buttons when I click on the

```
RAID, Delete(nope), Unplug(no), and Recover(which is the only option in my favor)
```

. Every time I press it, it says **Parameter Error**.
The RAID is still in disable but this data is important, though not everyone has $1000 lying around. And even if let's just say I don't need it right,****12TB**** gone.

No one has posted anything about enabling a RAID so I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you not have backups of the array?

Comment: No I don't btw it is a raid 5 with four 3tb disks so I would hate to see them be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to break the RAID and then use a RAID recovery software to recover data.